# select() returning 1 even in case process on remote host bound to a given port is killed

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have written a program using non-blocking `connect()` and `select()` combination to check the connection to a remote host at a 
particular port. `select()` has some timeout value also, in my case 2.5s. I am testing the program to connect to a process running the SMTP service on the remote host which is
which is bound to port 25 . If I kill that process running on remote host , then also `select()` returning 1 to tell that writing (socket added to write fd_set ) to that process 
is possible. What can be the reason behind this, and also Is it possible to use `select()` in this case. I tried using `connect()` which returns immediately when such connection is not possible but it doesn't work in case some timeout is required for connection, that is why I am using `select()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish by using another `connect()` after `select()` function call. 
Posting the code snippet

```
error = connect(soc, (struct sockaddr *)serveraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) ;

 if(error == 0){
        DIAGC("vsrserv", 1, "Returning while connect is 0");
        return 0;
}

if(errno != EINPROGRESS)
        return -1;


int retVal = select (soc+1, &writeFD, (fd_set *)NULL, (fd_set *)NULL, (struct timeval *)(&timeout));

if (retVal == 0){
        close(soc);
        return -1;
}

socklen_t len = 0;
int m = getsockopt(soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) ;

if(m < 0){
        close(soc);
        return -1;
}

//connect() returns immediately if it is able to connect to that particular port
//Since select() returned 1 it means host was reachable so just need to verify the port on the remote host which we can do with another with connect() call
error = connect(soc, (struct sockaddr *)serveraddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) ;

    if(error < 0){
        close(soc);
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`select()` doesn't tell you that reading or writing is possible, it just tells you that it won't block (or return the error `EWOULDBLOCK` if the socket is in non-blocking mode). A socket is always writable as long as the local socket buffer is not full. Also, if anything was sent after the remote process has died, you will receive a RST packet, and attempts to write after that will return `ECONNRESET` immediately. So the socket will be marked writable when that happens.

Comment: So this thing is possible only if I try write() to that address (to get ECONNRESET) or there is any other way.

Comment: If you try to connect when there's no server listening, you'll get `ECONNRESET` immediately, too.

Comment: In my case when remote host is up then `connect()` call sets errno as `EINPROGRESS` for a non-blocking socket which is expected. Thats why I am using `select()` to wait for the operation to be completed as per the specified timeout. Now what I am asking is, if `select()` doesn't take into account the port number of the host (I'm not sure about this) , how to proceed in this case .

Comment: Since the socket is non-blocking, `connect()` doesn't wait for a response from the server. So it can't tell if it will be a successful connection or it will get a reset, and just returns `EINPROGRESS`. `select` will report the socket is writable when it gets either type of response from the server.

Comment: `select` doesn't know or care about port numbers, that's handled by the socket driver.